# Create jodatime LocalDate from java.sql.Time

Tags: java, jodatime, localtime

I'm new to **joda-time** and I didn't find anywhere examples to do some simple things.

I want to make an object where to save a time value read from a table in a database (a `java.sql.Time` - e.g. `"18:30:00"`) I don't care about time zone, so I think that I need `LocalDate`. But the problem is that I couldn't create a `LocalDate` object based on that `Time` object.

I tried with no success `LocalDate.fromDateFields()`, `DateTimeParser.parseInto()`, `DateTimeParser.parseDateTime()`.

EDIT:
I should have used `LocalTime`.
These work:

```
java.sql.Time time = Time.valueOf("18:30:00");
LocalTime lt1 = LocalTime.fromDateFields(time);
LocalTime lt2 = new LocalTime(time);
```

Comment: `org.joda.time.LocalDate` represents a date, `java.sql.Time` represents a time. What meaningful conversion would you expect to get from that?

Comment: I saw that `YearMonthDay` and `TimeOfDay` were classes where you don't need all the datetime fields (partial).  But when I wanted to use them, there were deprecated and it said use `LocalDate` and `LocalTime`. Now I see that I should have used `LocalTime`. But it doesn't work with this neither.

Comment: How would one go the other around. I am trying to convert fom LocalTime to sql time, but I noticed the getMillis()* functions of LocalTime return ints. I want to void having to shuttle it through DateTime.

Comment: @DarkStar1: I think `getMillisOfDay()` would work, if you only need the time fields. They return ints because there are only 86,400,000 millis in a day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#LocalDate%28java.lang.Object%29), you should be able to construct a LocalDate directly by passing it a java.util.Date as the sole constructor argument. Since a java.sql.Time extends java.util.Date, you should be able to

```
final LocalDate ld = new LocalDate(mySqlTime);
```

This works for me:

```
System.out.println(new LocalDate(Time.valueOf("18:30:00")));
```

On the other hand, it's not a meaningful thing to do, since you'll always get January 1, 1970. But I imagine you know what you're doing.

Comment: I already tried `LocalDate ld = new LocalDate(Time.valueOf("18:30:00"));` and it gives `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: Only somewhat related, but using the `LocalDate` constructor with values from a database you have to be careful: `null` values will be converted into the current date (which may very well not be what you want).